# Can we write $2^\alpha$ as sum of smaller 2-powers when $\alpha\geqslant 5$ is a positive integer?

Tags: number-theory, binary

Let $\alpha$ be a positive integer $\geqslant 5$. Let us consider 
\begin{align*}
&B_1\subseteq \{0,1,2,3,4\}\\
&B_2\subseteq \mathbb{N}-\{0,1,2,3,4\}
\end{align*}
where $B_2$ can be finite or infinite. How to prove that 
$$2^\alpha=\sum\limits_{i\in B_1}2^i + \sum\limits_{i\in B_2}2^i$$
is an impossibility ?

Moreover, if not i.e. if the above expression be true, will it be unique expression ?

I was able to show the statement is true for $\alpha=5,6$. But don't know how shall I proceed in general. Can you help me in this regard ?

*Edit*

Here I am providing my own attempt. Request to all of you to please suggest or correct me if there be any mistake.

First of all, as $\alpha\geqslant 5$ so $B_2$ must not contain any positive integers $\geqslant \alpha$ otherwise the RHS will become at least $2^{\alpha}+1$ making it bigger than LHS.

Now we have $$2^\alpha=\sum\limits_{i\in \mathcal{B}}2^i$$ where $\mathcal{B}\subseteq B_1\cup B_2$.

But even if we consider the ultimate possibility $\mathcal{B}=\{0,1,2,\cdots, \alpha-1\}$ then RHS $=1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^{\alpha-1}=2^\alpha-1<2^\alpha$ which would be contradiction. If $\mathcal{B}$ be a finite subset of $\{0,1,2, \cdots, \alpha-1\}$ we shall still get contardiction.

Please tell me if there be any mistake I have made here

Comment: Does the partition into $B_1$ and $B_2$ do anything? Can't you just take $B\subseteq \Bbb N$ and look at $\sum_{i\in B}2^i$?

Comment: @Arthur actually I didn't think in that way, to be honest. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood, anyway to OP how did you prove it for $\alpha=6$ the proof should probably easily extend for all $\alpha$.

Comment: @Dr.Mathva $\sum_{i\in X}f(i)$ is pretty standard notation for "for each $i\in X$, calculate $f(i)$, then add together all the results". If $X$ is infinite, you have some convergence issues to tackle, you basically need absolute convergence.

Comment: Thanks, @Arthur, have never seen it...

Answer (score 1):

Formally there is possiblity $\mathcal B_1 = \varnothing$, $\mathcal B_2 = \{\alpha\}$. Your argument is correct, but we can prove it directly without appeal to sum of gemoetric sequence.

Let us prove that $2^\alpha = \sum\limits_{i \in \mathcal B} 2^i$ iff $\mathcal B = \{\alpha\}$ using induction on $\alpha$.

If $\alpha = 0$ then it's true, as would there be $\mathcal B \ni n > \alpha$ the sum would be greater then $1$, and would $\mathcal B$ be empty, the sum would be $0$.

If $\alpha > 0$ then $0 \notin \mathcal B$, otherwise the sum would be an odd number. Then let us define $\mathcal C = \{x - 1 | x \in \mathcal B\}$. We have $2^{\alpha - 1} = \frac{2^\alpha}{2} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i \in \mathcal B} 2^i}{2} = \sum\limits_{i \in \mathcal B} 2^{i - 1} = \sum\limits_{i \in \mathcal C}2^i$. By induction it implies $\mathcal C = \{\alpha - 1\}$, therefore $\mathcal B = \{\alpha\}$.